# HTTPRequest equivalent to cURL

Tags: json, vb.net, curl, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I have this particular cURL statement that I am trying to figure out the equivalent for it in an HTTP Request.

`curl -X POST --upload-file movie-data-2013.json doc-movies-123456789012.us-east-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/documents/batch --header "Content-Type:application/json"`

So far the HTTP Request equivalent I am able to compile is below:

```
Set oHTTPRequest = Server.CreateObject( "MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0" ) 
oHTTPRequest.Open "POST" _
              ,"doc-movies-123456789012.us-east-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/documents/batch" _
              False
oHTTPRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/json"
oHTTPRequest.Send
```

For the most part I should be set, except there's one part it's missing, and I'm unsure how it's appended to the request.

There is a part in cURL that says: `--upload-file movie-data-2013.json`
Not sure how it applies in an HTTP Request. Does anyone how this applies?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend trying .Net's built-in [HttpWebRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) over MSXML. There is an example of uploading text data on MSDN using the [GetRequestStream method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4cek6cc(v=vs.110).aspx). You should be able to easily modify the sample to instead read the data from a file, for example using [File.ReadAllBytes](http://system.io.file.readallbytes), and then write the returned data to the request stream.